# Should my Kalman filter outperform a filter-less estimate of location?

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I built a toy Kalman filter to estimate velocity and acceleration of a system (1-dimensional to start), and I'm surprised that I can't get better location estimates than by calculating location without any filter at all.

As far as I can tell, I'm following some Kalman filter examples by-the-book. However, these examples don't explicitly show that the Kalman filter made any improvement over simpler processing alternatives, so I'm not sure if this is a scenario in which a Kalman filter should perform well.

**Toy Kalman filter**

- Fake location generated, e.g. 1000 samples over a period of a sine wave
- Fake velocity data derived from fake location data, Gaussian noise added
- Fake acceleration data derived from fake location data, Gaussian noise added
- Kalman filter estimates state [ acceleration   velocity ]

  - F = [ [ 1  0 ] [ dt  1 ] ]
  - Q = covariance( acceleration data, velocity data )
  - R = covariance( acceleration noise, velocity noise )

**Evaluation: estimating final location**

Location is integrated using $x_k = x_{k-1} + \frac{v_k+v_{k-1}}{2}dt + \frac{1}{2}\frac{a_k+a_{k-1}}{2}dt^2$. I'm comparing two final location estimates to the true final location: the estimate using $a$ and $v$ from the Kalman filter, and the estimate using the noisy $a$ and $v$ data. In this comparison, at best I can get the Kalman filter location error to equal the simple no-filter error.

**Things I've tried**

- making the noise asymmetric -- no change in Kalman performance over simpler process
- changing amplitude of noise, either and both of acc. and vel. -- again, no change
- making the noise scale time-dependent -- no change
- changing process matrices R and Q -- Kalman worsens with any change
- applying to 2-D, using a fake yaw rate measurement. The thought is that symmetrical velocity and yaw errors won't cancel in two dimensions, so estimates averaging closer to truth will perform better -- no improvement by Kalman

**Sub-questions (which may answer the Question):**

- **Do I need to have a direct measurement method of the desired state (location) for Kalman to be useful (does integration undo the filtering)?**
- **Does Kalman only work when I have a known feedback? E.g., if this were a car, the filter only performs better than a simple algorithm if the throttle is a measured input?**

---

Here's an example of the data I'm generating in python:

```
import numpy as np

sz = 1000                                             # size of data
dt = 1                                                # time interval
t = np.arange(sz*dt, step=dt)                         # time array

loc = -0.1*sz*np.sin(t*10/sz) + sz*np.sin(t/sz)      # 1-D location vs. time
vel = -np.cos(t*10/sz) + np.cos(t/sz)                # velocity (speed in 1-D for now)
acc = 10/sz*np.sin(t*10/sz) + -1/sz*np.sin(t/sz)     # acceleration

# acceleration data with noise
acc_noise = 1e-2                        
acc_data = acc + np.random.normal(loc=0., scale=acc_noise, size=sz) 

# velocity data with noise
vel_noise = 1e-1              
vel_data = vel + np.random.normal(loc=0., scale=vel_noise, size=sz)
```

[image: acceleration from Kalman]
[image: velocity from Kalman]
[image: location from Kalman]

Comment: why didn't you have position in your state vector? even if you don't have any position measurements you should add the position to the state.

Comment: can you please post your toy data (as an external link if it works), so I can perform filtering and see what happens?

Comment: @Anton "you should add the position to the state" -- would this result in a more accurate position estimate? I thought since I have no position measurement it's equivalent to calculate it afterwards by integrating velocity and acceleration.

Comment: @Anton I edited to add code generating some example data. Thank you.

Comment: By adding the position to your state vector you have following advantages: 1. you don't need to calculate the position from your other states (especially if the calculation is not really strait forward). 2. You get a new entry in your Q-Matrix, so you can affect your v and a estimation by defining the appropriate dynamic of the position.

Comment: Do you have some plots with your estimation results and comparison to the ground truth?

Comment: @Anton I added plots of Kalman vs. Measurement vs. Truth for acceleration, velocity, and location. Note, I also changed the noise scales in the code to make the error more obvious in the plots.
_Also note_, there are 1000 Kalman estimates, but I wrote my code to only plot 100 (things got cramped when I was plotting all N for N > 1000)